# How do I access the Kubernetes api from within a pod container?

Tags: kubernetes

I used to be able to curl

```
https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1beta3/namespaces/default/
```

as my base URL, but in kubernetes 0.18.0 it gives me "unauthorized". The strange thing is that if I used the external IP address of the API machine (`http://172.17.8.101:8080/api/v1beta3/namespaces/default/`), it works just fine.

Comment: Where are you running your cluster (GCE, AWS, etc) and using what base OS (debian, CoreOS, etc)?

Comment: Vagrant/CoreOS...i will eventually move it to AWS/CoreOS

Comment: Where do the `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` and `$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT` variables come from?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

In the official documentation I found this:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod

Apparently I was missing a security token that I didn't need in a previous version of Kubernetes. From that, I devised what I think is a simpler solution than running a proxy or installing golang on my container. See this example that gets the information, from the api, for the current container:

```
KUBE_TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
curl -sSk -H "Authorization: Bearer $KUBE_TOKEN" \
      https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$HOSTNAME
```

I also use include a simple binary, jq (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/), to parse the json for use in bash scripts.

Comment: For recently deployed clusters you might want to change `v1beta3` to `v1`

Comment: Note that this curl command will connect *insecurely* to the apiserver (making it possible for a man-in-the-middle to intercept the bearer token), so you should only use it if the network between the pod and the apiserver is fully trusted. Otherwise, you should pass the `--cacert` flag to curl so that curl validates the certificate presented by the apiserver.

Comment: I had to use `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=kubernetes.default`, `$KUBERNETES_443_TCP_PORT=443`, NAMESPACE==$(</var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace)`. The URL was `https://kubernetes.default:443/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/pods/$HOSTNAME`. Note that the API version is set to v1 instead of v1beta3 and the default namespace was replaced with $NAMESPACE.

Answer (score 92):

Every pod has a service account automatically applied that allows it to access the apiserver. The service account provides both client credentials, in the form of a bearer token, and the certificate authority certificate that was used to sign the certificate presented by the apiserver. With these two pieces of information, you can create a secure, authenticated connection to the apisever without using `curl -k` (aka `curl --insecure`):

```
curl -v --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" https://kubernetes.default.svc/
```

Comment: It should be noted that in order for the cacert and token to both exist in the service account, the replication-controller must be given a `--root-ca-file=` argument when started. (this is handled automatically in most of the kubernetes installers). See discussion here for more details: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/10265

Comment: I was accessing the API server from a pod with a different namespace. Thus I had to use `https://kubernetes.default/` as host

Comment: Official host is `kubernetes.default.svc` as documented at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod

Answer (score 20):

Using the Python kubernetes client..

```py
    from kubernetes import client, config

    config.load_incluster_config()
    v1_core = client.CoreV1Api()
```

Comment: Thanks! Here is a small [repo](https://github.com/omerlh/pod_kube_api_demo) with an example, based on your answer, to make it simpler to play with this code.

Answer (score 13):

wget version:

```
KUBE_TOKEN=$(</var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)    
wget -vO- --ca-certificate /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt  --header "Authorization: Bearer $KUBE_TOKEN" https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 7):

From inside the pod, kubernetes api server can be accessible directly on "https://kubernetes.default". By default it uses the "default service account" for accessing the api server.

So, we also need to pass a "ca cert" and "default service account token" to authenticate with the api server.

certificate file is stored at the following location inside the pod :
/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt

and the default service account token at :
/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

You can use the [nodejs kubbernetes godaddy client](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client).

```html
let getRequestInfo = () => {
    return {
        url: "https://kubernetes.default",
        ca:   fs.readFileSync('/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt').toString(),
        auth: {
            bearer: fs.readFileSync('/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token').toString(),
        },
        timeout: 1500
    };
}

let initK8objs = () =>{
    k8obj = getRequestInfo();
    k8score = new Api.Core(k8obj),
    k8s = new Api.Api(k8obj);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The most important addendum to the details already mentioned above is that the pod from which you are trying to access the API server should have the RBAC capabilities to do so.

Each entity in the k8s system is identified by a service-account (like user account being used for users). Based on the RBAC capabilities, the service account token (/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token) is populated.  The kube-api bindings (e.g. pykube) can take this token as a input when creating connection to the kube-api-servers. If the pod has the right RBAC capabilities, the pod would be able to establish the connection with the kube-api server.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue when trying to access the API from inside a pod using Go Code. Below is what I implemented to get that working, should someone come across this question wanting to use Go too.

The example uses a pod resource, for which you should use the `client-go` library if you are working with native kubernetes objects. The code is more helpful for those working with CustomResourceDefintions.

```
serviceHost := os.GetEnv("KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST")
servicePort := os.GetEnv("KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT")
apiVersion := "v1" // For example
namespace := default // For example
resource := "pod" // For example
httpMethod := http.MethodGet // For Example

url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s:%s/apis/%s/namespaces/%s/%s", serviceHost, servicePort, apiVersion, namespace, resource)

u, err := url.Parse(url)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
req, err := http.NewRequest(httpMethod, u.String(), bytes.NewBuffer(payload))
if err != nil {
    return err
}

caToken, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token")
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // cannot find token file
}

req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", string(caToken)))

caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt")
if err != nil {
    return panic(err) // Can't find cert file
}
caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

client := &http.Client{
  Transport: &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        RootCAs: caCertPool,
    },
  },
}

resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("sending helm deploy payload failed: %s", err.Error())
    return err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

// Check resp.StatusCode
// Check resp.Status
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar auth problem on GKE where python scripts suddenly threw exceptions. The solution that worked for me was to give pods permission through role

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: fabric8-rbac
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
  # Reference to upper's `metadata.name`
  name: default
  # Reference to upper's `metadata.namespace`
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

for more information [enter link description here](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/issues/6840)

Answer (score 5):

*`This is from the` [Kubernetes In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617293725) `book.`*

You need to take care of **authentication**. The API server  itself  says  you’re  not  authorized  to  access  it,  because  **it  doesn’t  know  who you are**.

To authenticate, you need an **authentication token.** Luckily, the token is provided through the **default-token Secret** mentioned  previously,  and  is  stored  in  the  token  file  in  the  secret  volume.

*You’re going to use the **token** to access the API server*. First, load the token into an environment variable:

```
root@myhome:/# TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
```

The token is now stored in the **TOKEN** **environment** **variable**. You can use it when sending requests to the API server:

```
root@curl:/# curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"  https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$HOSTNAME
   {  "paths": 
      [    
        "/api",    
        "/api/v1",   
        "/apis",    
        "/apis/apps",    
        "/apis/apps/v1beta1",    
        "/apis/authorization.k8s.io",        
         ...    
        "/ui/",    
        "/version"  
      ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

With RBAC enabled, default service account don't have any permissions.

Better create separate service account for your needs and use it to create your pod.

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: secret-access-sa
  containers:
    ...
```

It's well explained here https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/service-accounts-and-auditing-in-kubernetes/

Answer (score 2):

For whoever is using Google Container Engine (powered by Kubernetes):

A simple call to `https://kubernetes` from within the cluster using [this kubernetes client for Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.fabric8/kubernetes-client) works.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -v -cacert <path to>/ca.crt --cert <path to>/kubernetes-node.crt --key <path to>/kubernetes-node.key https://<ip:port>
```

My k8s version is 1.2.0, and in other versions it's supposed to work too^ ^

Comment: The above is correct if you have webhooks or some other RBAC enabled.  This is especially true >1.2 of k8s