# kubernetes api using an unreachable cluster IP

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

This is odd. Did i miss something during the setup

```
master kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster # kubectl get svc kubernetes
NAME         LABELS                                    SELECTOR   IP(S)        PORT(S)
kubernetes   component=apiserver,provider=kubernetes   <none>     10.100.0.1   8080/TCP
```

I can't seem to reach the 10.100.0.1 address from anywhere on the cluster. However, some of the other clusterIP address are reachable from the nodes

```
master kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster # kubectl get svc elasticsearch
NAME            LABELS                                SELECTOR                              IP(S)            PORT(S)
elasticsearch   component=elasticsearch,role=client   component=elasticsearch,role=client   10.100.213.223   9200/TCP
```

I believe this is causing the problem i am having when i look at the logs for the elasticsearch pods.

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://10.100.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/endpoints/elasticsearch-discovery: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

But if i check that same path with another address the items are retuned

```
# curl http://10.1.141.41:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/endpoints/elasticsearch-discovery
{
  "kind": "Endpoints",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
......
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace actually indicates that you *can* reach `10.100.0.1` but that your client is not able to verify the certificate presented by the Kubernetes apiserver. If you want to connect using SSL, you should verify that the certificate used by the Kubernetes apiserver has `10.100.0.1` as an IP in the subject alternate names field or you could use the DNS name for the service (and likewise ensure that it is listed in the certificate).

Comment: Thank you for that. It makes complete sense. I am trying to trouble shoot this and would like to completely disable the ssl check or force the insecure port to be used when the kubelet and kube-api are talking. I am trying to add in insecure-skip-tls-verify: true

Comment: The stack trace indicates that it isn't a problem with the kubelet -> kube-apiserver. It's a problem with the elastic search pods (where the stack trace comes from). So you want to force insecure from the elastic search pod -> kube-apiserver. If you are using the standard elastic search add-on (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/elasticsearch/es-rc.yaml) you should make sure that you are passing your certificate to the node controller process so that it can create service account certificates.

Comment: Robert, thanks again. Yes i am using the standard elastic search add-on. I have copied the two files from the master /run/kubernetes/apiserver.{crt|key}. To the minions. I then modified the rc yaml files and changed the path for KUBERNETES_CA_CERTIFICATE_FILE's value to /data/apiserver.crt. I made sure the /data volume is mounted (default in above example). When i re-created the rc, i attched into the docker image expecting to see the /data/apiserver.crt mounted, but i did not. I did see the env variable's value for the KUBERNETES_CA_CERTIFICATE_FILE changed to the /data/apiserver.crt.

Comment: It's not the apiserver.{crt|key} that you want on the minions. If you pass the private key to the node controller, you should be able to securely contact the apiserver from within a pod -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690186/how-do-i-access-the-kubernetes-api-from-within-a-pod-container

Answer (score 0):

First i had to make the certs
    ./make-ca-cert.sh  IP:           ,IP:10.0.0.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local

Then i had to update the kube api server and the kube controller
kube-apiserver

```
--client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt
--tls-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.cert
--tls-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key
key
--    admission_control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota

kube-controller-manager

--root-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt
--service-account-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key
```

I then coppied the ca.crt and kubecfg.{crt|key} to the minions, and correctly call them from the kubeconfig file
/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/ssl/private/kubecfg.crt
    client-key: /etc/ssl/private/kubecfg.key
clusters:
- name: cluster01
  cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster01
    user: kubelet
  name: service-account-context
current-context: service-account-context
```

Finally thanks to lewismarshall https://github.com/UKHomeOffice/docker-elasticsearch/blob/master/examples/kubernetes.md

I updated all the rc-yaml files.

I am now getting a 200!
    master kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster # curl http://10.244.52.18:9200
    {
      "status" : 200,
    ....

Now i can't figure out why i am not able to load a plugin on the client node.

## /elasticsearch/bin/plugin  -install royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'DISCOVERY_SERVICE'