# how to authenticate to google container engine kubernetes API server using either k8s REST or fabric8 API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to write a service that spawns container based applications within a Kubernetes cluster.  I'd like  to do some testing against 
Google Container Engine as a baseline; however, I am having trouble figuring
out how to get my REST client to authenticate with the k8s API server (the master).

I came across a good hint here: http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/9c6a16719a43/google-container-engine-rest-api-authorization.html

The author says "I know that OAuth works [against Google Container Engine]", and they sound knowledgable.  So, I'm thinking of trying oauth (I guess oauth2.) However, trial and error will take me a lot longer than adapting from some working code that works against Google Container Engine via either the 
k8s REST or fabric8 API.

If anyone can give me a pointer to such code, or even discussions of such code,  I'd appreciate it very much !   thanks /chris

Comment: Are you trying to spawn container clusters (using the Google Container Engine REST API) or applications in an existing container cluster (using the Kubernetes REST API)?

Comment: -  answer is:   The latter.   I manually created the container clusters. my test code is trying to spawn nginx (and wrap a load balanced service around it) via fabric8 rest API.. which is a convenience layer on top of k8s REST api.   code is here ->  https://github.com/buildlackey/fabric8-k8s-fiddling      Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kubernetes apiserver doesn't (yet) work with OAuth, so you will need to use one of the supported authentication mechanisms (http basic auth, bearer token auth, or client certificates) when making API requests.

Every pod has a service account automatically applied that allows it to access the apiserver using a bearer token. See [How do I access the Kubernetes api from within a pod container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690186/how-do-i-access-the-kubernetes-api-from-within-a-pod-container/33109739#33109739).

With the credentials from the service account, you can deploy an application that will create new objects in the system (pods, replication controllers, etc) to spawn container based applications.