# Like to know Kubernetes API server Host from the app deployed on to POD in a cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Like to know if there is a way to identify Master IP address (API server Host & port) from the application that I run in POD?. ( say I create a kubernetes cluster A, with Master public IP address x.x.x.x; and I create a pod with my app (say a golang or J2ee) on a kubernetes minion belonging to that cluster A. From the App process that is running on cluster A minion , we like to know the public IP address of that Master (x.x.x.x) )

I do not find any Environmental variables for the same.

Can any one help?.

Comment: I thought your question was good, maybe phrase it: In Kubernetes How to get Cluster or Service Host and port from pod.

Answer (score 2):

The api service is exposed via a k8s service. You would need to use the API to access the service config. You can get access to the API through the service endpoint (the address is in an env variable) but you'll have to have the necessary creds to do anything useful. They're in a subdirectory of `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io` depending on which service account your pod is running under. You can either access the endpoint directly, over https or you can run a proxy in your pod. See http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod.

An example of using `curl` to hit the API server is given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739416/191215.

The api endpoint you want is `/api/v1/endpoints`. Look for the `item` with a `metadata.name` of `kubernetes`. The external endpoint should be one of the `subsets` `addresses`.

I believe this is true for all k8s implementations but have only tested it on GKE and from `docker-machine`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that we can use DNS name "kuberenets.default" for accessing the API server. I like to explain my problem little more as the above is not helping me to resolve the problem. Once the cluster is created using the kube_up we get a config file for the cluster, which contains "server: https://<Public IP Address>" , I like to get this IP Address from the pod. When I tried the DNS name "kubernetes.default" it does not provide me the public IP Address.

Comment: You still didn't say why you want to get this IP from the POD but w/e. In any case, you should be able to get the address from the service as an endpoint. For example, kubectl can get it via `kubectl describe service kubernetes` You can do the same thing via the API/`curl` to the private service address. But you'll need creds to access the API endpoint. PODs don't have privileged access to k8s controls.

Comment: I am sorry , did not explain why I require this. I have a multi cluster environment where the cluster details are stored in the zookeeper; since the cluster details are fetched from the config file generated post kube_up, the Server details "https://public IP address of Master" is stored in the zookeeper; the App Need to fetch the details from the zookeeper and correlate to find to which cluster it belongs to and perform operation accordingly.  it would be helpful if I can get the cluster ID (Name) using the rest API.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the above mentioned details does not provide the public IP ; it provides only the private IP address.

Comment: You don't say what cluster you're running against. The API results definitely include the external address for GKE and docker-machine.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS name `kubernetes` should resolve to a virtual IP address that will route to the master so that you can hit the apiserver.

Comment: Thanks for the Swift response.  I was not able to resolve the DNS Name "kubernetes" from the docker or from node.

Comment: DNS name "kubernetes" did not work; However "kubernetes.default" worked , but it does not provide me the Public IP address of the Master; Once the Master is created we would have a public IP address in the cluster config created via kube_up.sh, I like to get that IP address in app running in  a pod.