# Network endpoints are disabled after container in a Job pod exits and sidecar container is still running

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Job pod with two containers, *worker* and *sidecar*. The sidecar container exposes a REST API via a service.

While the worker container is active, the sidecar container REST API functions as expected.

However, after the worker completes/exits, the sidecar is no longer reachable. I was able to determine that the network endpoints become disabled once the worker container exits.

Is it possible to configure the pod such that the network endpoints remain active as long as there are still containers running in the pod?

Comment: Why do you need sidecar for Job resource? Maybe it will be better to use custom Job `operator` which can track and handle job execution?

Comment: As you suspected, the sidecar does some cleanup. I'm not familiar with operators. Is this a new feature? Could you please point me to docs? I found this but I'm not sure if that's what you are referring to: https://coreos.com/operators/

Comment: Ok, clean up seems to be necessary for the task. If you want to track current situation about your issue, check links: [Issue about Job sidecar support](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25908) [SIG about sidecar support enhancement](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-apps/sidecarcontainers.md)

Comment: What's about Operator SDK - it's a way to implement pod management for custom resources with specific functionality and lifecycle. For example, [airflow-operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/airflow-operator) implements integration of Apache Airflow with k8s. Other example is [spark-operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator). Sometimes it's simpler to create custom scheduler or use [downward API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208211/sidecar-containers-in-kubernetes-jobs).

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour as of https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup.

Comment: Right, that's what I was able to gather from the docs as well. I was asking whether it's possible to configure the pod for different behavior.

Comment: Hey, super sorry I missed your answer.
As far as I know, it is not.