# Blocking access to the Kubernetes API from containers in Google Container Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

As far as I've been able to see, it is not yet possible to control Kubernetes API access from containers deployed on a Google-managed Kubernetes cluster. All containers get a token mounted as a secret and environment variables with information about the endpoint.

I am exploring the possibility of allowing users to upload code that gets deployed into containers in the cluster and I would like to block access to the API. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739416/270628.

To enable ABAC or any other type of control for the cluster, I would have to deploy my own Kubertenes cluster through GCP. I'd like to avoid having to do this.

So, is it possible to prevent the mounting of those secrets or perhaps remove those secrets upon pod creation? If so, is there a recommended way?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it isn't possible to create a pod without the service account being added (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16779). If you have control over the yaml files that create pods, you can follow [this advice](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16779#issuecomment-157460294) to mount an `emptyDir` volume on top of the service account to prevent the pod from accessing the credentials.