# Get image name within container

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to get the name of the container image from within the container.

I tried to look around the Downward APIs, but it seems that it's not possible:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/

For now my workaround is:

```
      env:
        - name: IMAGE
          value: "myimage:latest"
```

Is there maybe a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is probably OK, assuming you build your containers with CI/CD. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690186/how-do-i-access-the-kubernetes-api-from-within-a-pod-container) about how to access the kubernetes API from within a cluster as an alternative. Here's the link to [POD API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/#pod-v1-core) which should contain the image information.