# Kubernetes API Access from Pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm trying to access the Kubernetes API in order to discover pods from within a deployed container. Although I'll do this programatically, right now, I'm just using cURL to check for issues.

I run this from a pod terminal:

```
curl -vvv -H "Authorization: Bearer $(</var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" "https://kubernetes.default/api/v1/namespaces/$(</var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace)/endpoints" --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
```

And I get a 403 result:

```
* About to connect() to kubernetes.default port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 172.30.0.1...
* Connected to kubernetes.default (172.30.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=10.0.75.2
*       start date: Nov 23 16:55:27 2017 GMT
*       expire date: Nov 23 16:55:28 2019 GMT
*       common name: 10.0.75.2
*       issuer: CN=openshift-signer@1511456125
> GET /api/v1/namespaces/myproject/endpoints HTTP/1.1                                                                                            s/$(</var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serv
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: kubernetes.default
> Accept: */*> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJteXByb2plY3QiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlY3JldC5uYW1lIjoiZGVmYXVsdC10b2tlbi00cXZidCIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50Lm5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZXJ2aWNlLWFjY291bnQudWlkIjoiMjg3NzAzYjEtZDA4OC0xMWU3LTkzZjQtNmEyNGZhYWZjYzQxIiwic3ViIjoic3lzdGVtOnNlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Om15cHJvamVjdDpkZWZhdWx0In0.yl2HUhmxjrb4UqkAioq1TixWl_YqUPoxSvQPPSgl9Hzr97Hjm7icdL_mdptwEnOSErfzqSUBiMKJcIRdIa3Z7mfkgEk-f2H-M7TUU8GpXmD2Zex6Bcn_dq-Hsoed6W2PYpeFDoy98p5rSNTUL5MPMATOodeAulB0NG_zF01-8qTbLO_I6FRa3BCVXVMaZWBoZgwZ1acQbd4fJqDRsYmQMSi5P8a3nYgjBdifkQeTTb3S8Kmnszct41LoUlh9Xv29YVEyr1uQc5DSLAgQKj_NdSxkVq-MJP8z1PWV3OmHULNChocXr7RGKaNwlVpwpgNqsDAOqIyE1ozxlntIrotLBw
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Thu, 23 Nov 2017 22:18:01 GMT
< Content-Length: 282
<
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "User \"system:serviceaccount:myproject:default\" cannot list endpoints in project \"myproject\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "endpoints"
  },
  "code": 403
}
* Connection #0 to host kubernetes.default left intact
```

I've tried to access a number of resources, like, endpoints, pods, etc. I've also omitted the namespace (as to access the whole cluster resources) to no avail.

I'm currently using OpenShift Origin, clean (just ran `oc cluster up` and deployed a test image to access the terminal in the web console).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690186/how-do-i-access-the-kubernetes-api-from-within-a-pod-container

Comment: Hey @MartinBroadhurst, the question is *very* similar, however, I'm not missing the Authentication header. My guess is that some configuration is preventing me (forbidding) to access the resource.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're on fully RBAC enabled cluster, and your default service account `system:serviceaccount:myproject:default`, as expected, is unauthorised. You should create and use dedicated service account for this pod and explicitly grant it access to what it needs to read.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/

Comment: You could still use the ``default`` service account for the project, don't need to use a separate service account unless really had to. To allow application running under default service account read only access to REST API in OpenShift, run ``oc policy add-role-to-user view -z default`` when the project you want to apply it to is the current project.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton you could, but you should NOT to. This is the least privilege rule. Why grant every pod in namespace (so using default sa) access to kube API ?

Comment: If going to seperate things properly, you wouldn't have all your applications in one project. You would separate things into different projects and if they needed to communicate with each other selectively open up pod networks to allow it. Ultimately there are many ways of doing things, it really comes down to the applications and what you are happy doing. So yes you can use a service account, but as first step, easier to apply access to ``default`` to get it going. Then can work out extra steps to create separate service account and have pod use it.

Comment: Hey guys, I thought it was something like it, but was wishing it was something else. I'll try it out.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton since I'm using OpenShift, you're right. I can grant the default user view access to the whole namespace, which is only a single application (where I desire that default has this kind of access). Could you create an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass an authorization token bearer within curl command. Without it, it's expected to be unauthorized.

More at: [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/)