# Connecting to Kubernetes API from pod

Tags: api, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I'm trying to use Kubernetes API from inside a pod. Going to list/watch pods and custom defined resources.

Construct url as "https://KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS"
Authorization header = "Bearer /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token"
CaCert = /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt

When running inside minikube, the request fails with "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.96.0.1:443"
Same code running in GCP fails with: "Error: unable to verify the first certificate"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690186/how-do-i-access-the-kubernetes-api-from-within-a-pod-container This link has a few solutions you can try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access the Kubernetes api from within a pod container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690186/how-do-i-access-the-kubernetes-api-from-within-a-pod-container)

Comment: While the question in those posts have similar title, the actual problems are different. In case of minikube I'm not able to connect to the api server. when running in GCP there are some problems with the certificate.

Comment: I've also tried this tutorial, but am getting the same behaviour. https://medium.com/@pczarkowski/the-kubernetes-api-call-is-coming-from-inside-the-cluster-f1a115bd2066

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `curl`, you can skip certificate checks with the `-k` flag.

Try

```
curl -k  https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces -H "Authorization: Bearer <content of /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token here>"
```