# Kubernetes Cron job invocation from pod

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to invoke a kubernetes Cron job inside a pod . Like I have to run this job from the application running in pod .

Do I have to use kubectl inside the pod to execute the job .

Appreciate your help

Comment: You can use the API/SDK to do this instead of kubectl. This will use the Service account feature available to the pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use the Default Service Account to access the API server. When you
>   create a pod, if you do not specify a service account, it is
>   automatically assigned the default service account in the same
>   namespace. If you get the raw json or yaml for a pod you have created
>   (for example, kubectl get pods/ -o yaml), you can see the
>   spec.serviceAccountName field has been automatically set.
>
> You can access the API from inside a pod using automatically mounted
>   service account credentials, as described in Accessing the Cluster.
>   The API permissions of the service account depend on the authorization
>   plugin and policy in use.
>
> In version 1.6+, you can opt out of automounting API credentials for a
>   service account by setting automountServiceAccountToken: false on the
>   service account

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/

1. So the First task is to either grant the permission of doing what you need to create to the default service account of the pod OR create a custom service account and use it inside the pod
2. Programatically access the API server using that service account to create the job you need
3. It could be just a simple curl POST to the API server from inside the pod with the json for the job creation

[How do I access the Kubernetes api from within a pod container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690186/how-do-i-access-the-kubernetes-api-from-within-a-pod-container)

you can also use the application specific SDK , for example if you have a python application , you can import kubernetes and run the job.